# 1998 Galant not starting, has no thermostat

Tags: starting, mitsubishi, thermostat, galant

The car has a new battery and new starter, but no thermostat.

The battery seems to be drained - the headlights will not come on, there is no clicking sound when I try to start and it won't even crank. It 30 degrees outside.

Can the absence of thermostat do this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What is not clear is whether you mean 30 °C or 30 °F. Also, could you start the car immediately after installing the new battery (in other words, is it possible that the battery might have drained after some time which is why it is not starting)?

Answer (score 1):

A thermostat disabling all electricity is unlikely. If you have a multimeter or voltmeter, check that your battery is charged, even new ones can be faulty. It should be over 12V.

If it has and still nothing electrical works (interior lights, ignition etc.) make sure the cables that connects your battery are clean and tight, where attached to the chassis as well as on the battery.

Also check that your vehicle doesn't have a main switch that is turned off (check users manual or follow your battery cables).

Answer (score 1):

Since the '98 Galant has a mechanical thermostat, it should start even with the thermostat removed.

Comment: If the OP can answer my questions in the [comment](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21848/1998-galant-not-starting-has-no-thermostat/21851#comment32437_21848) it should make it easier to point him in the right direction as to what might be wrong.